# Reemplazar valores de varias variables en un dataframe de manera eficiente en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, variables, dataframe

Buenas tardes desde Canarias. Estoy trabajando con la Encuesta Nacional de Salud en España (**ENSE**) para los dos últimos años que se han elaborado (2011 y 2017). El caso es que hay muchas variables cuya respuesta es binaria (sí o no,hombre o mujer, A o B, etc), las repsuestas se guardan en forma númerica, pero por alguna razón que desconozco no se han registrado con los valores `(1 y 0)`, sino que en algunas ocasiones se registraron como `(1 y 2)` y en otras como `(1 y 6)`.

**Necesito cambiar esos valores de `(2 y 6)` a `(0)`**, lo he conseguido pero me parece una forma muy ineficiente por su extensión y su redundancia por decirlo de alguna forma. Además, esta forma genera una variable fuera del dataframe por cada una que he cambiado, llenando de espacio innecesario mi ventana de entorno global **¿Cómo puedo conseguir este cambio de manera más limpia, menos extensa y menos repetitiva?**

Es necesario que la forma de hacerlo exija la selección de variables dentro de cada dataframe, ya que hay muchas otras variables que contienen los valores `(2 y 6)` pero que **NO** corresponden a una pregunta cuya respuesta sea de 2 opciones. Además, con el fin de explicar más claramente mi problema, he comentado que las variables solo toman 2 valores, pero **la mayoría de ellas admite también 2 respuestas más** (no sabe y no contesta) a las cuales se les asigna otros valores númericos(en la mayoría de los casos `(8 y 9)`); también se admite, solo en algunas variables, la opción de no contestar a esa pregunta ( Admite blanco por flujo).

Para que se entienda mejor el fragmento de código:

- los dataframes se llaman DATA_2011 y DATA_2017
- Las variables están codificadas y cada una corresponde a una pregunta de la    ENSE
- Cada encuesta se divide en 2 partes: Encuesta de adultos y encuesta de los hogares
- Si la variable no tiene ningún comentario al lado, significa que solo tiene dos valores, que no daba la opción de no contestar a esa pregunta y que tampoco daba la opción de contestar no sabe, ni no contesta.

```r
attach(DATA_2011)

# Adultos 2011
SEXOa[SEXOa == 2] <-0
PROXY_0[PROXY_0==6]<-0
PROXY_2[PROXY_2==6]<-0 # Admite blanco por flujo
PROXY_3a[PROXY_3a==2]<-0 # Admite blanco por flujo
E1_1[E1_1==2]<-0 # NS/NC
F11[F11==6]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
G20[G20==6]<-0 # NS/NC
H22[H22==6]<-0
J27_1[J27_1==6]<-0
J28_1[J28_1==6]<-0 # NS/NC
O60[O60==6]<-0
S106a_1[S106a_1==6]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
T122[T122==6]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
S106a_3[S106a_3==6]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
DEPFUNC1[DEPFUNC1==6]<-0 # ABpF, no consta
DEPFUNC2[DEPFUNC2==6]<-0 # ABpF, no consta
DEPFUNC3[DEPFUNC3==6]<-0 # ABpF, no consta

# Hogares 2011
SEXO_i[SEXO_i==6]<-0
A7_1_i[A7_1_i==6]<-0
A8_2_i[A8_2_i==6]<-0
A11_1_i[A11_1_i==6]<-0
A11_2_i[A11_2_i==6]<-0
A11_3_i[A11_3_i==6]<-0
A11_4_i[A11_4_i==6]<-0
A11_5_i[A11_5_i==6]<-0
A11_6_i[A11_6_i==6]<-0
A11_7_i[A11_7_i==6]<-0
A11_8_i[A11_8_i==6]<-0
B14[B14==6]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
B18[B18==6]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
CADULTO[CADULTO==6]<-0
CMENOR[CMENOR==6]<-0
D26_1[D26_1==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_2[D26_2==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_3[D26_3==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_4[D26_4==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_5[D26_5==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_6[D26_6==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_7[D26_7==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_8[D26_8==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_9[D26_9==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_10[D26_10==6]<-0 # ABpF
D26_11[D26_11==6]<-0 # ABpF
detach(DATA_2011)

attach(DATA_2017)

# Adultos 2017
SEXOa[SEXOa == 2] <- 0
PROXY_0[PROXY_0==2]<-0
PROXY_2[PROXY_2==2]<-0 # Admite blanco por flujo
PROXY_3b[PROXY_3b==2]<-0 # Admite blanco por flujo
E1_1[E1_1==2]<-0 # NS/NC
F7[F7==2]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
F12[F12==2]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
F16[F16==2]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
G22[G22==2]<-0 # NS/NC
H26_1[H26_1==2]<-0 # NS/NC
H26_2[H26_2==2]<-0 # NS/NC
H26_3[H26_3==2]<-0 # NS/NC
O66[O66==2]<-0
O69[O69==2]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
J27_1[J27_1==6]<-0
J28_1[J28_1==6]<-0 # NS/NC
O60[O60==6]<-0
O84_1[O84_1==2]<-0
O84_2[O84_2==2]<-0
O84_3[O84_3==2]<-0
O84_4[O84_4==2]<-0
O84_5[O84_5==2]<-0
O84_6[O84_6==2]<-0
O84_7[O84_7==2]<-0
O84_8[O84_8==2]<-0
O84_9[O84_9==2]<-0

# Hogares 2017
SEXO_i[SEXO_i==2]<-0
A7_1_i[A7_1_i==2]<-0
A8_1_i[A8_1_i==6]<-0
B14[B14==2]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
B18[B18==2]<-0 # ABpF , NS/NC
# Revisar los 6 y los 2
D26_1[D26_1==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_2[D26_2==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_3[D26_3==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_4[D26_4==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_5[D26_5==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_6[D26_6==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_7[D26_7==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_8[D26_8==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_9[D26_9==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_10[D26_10==2]<-0 # ABpF
D26_11[D26_11==2]<-0 # ABpF
detach(DATA_2017)
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como primer medida, trabajaría directamente con el `data.frame`, y no con las columnas de forma individual. El problema parece reducirse a: *"Hay ciertas columnas con un valor 2 que deben pasar a ser 0 y otras con el valor 6 que también deberán ser 0"*. Veamos un ejemplo algo más reducido al tuyo pero que sirve para ejemplificar:

```
set.seed(1)
DATA_2011 <- data.frame(tipo=LETTERS[1:5],
                        SEXOa=sample(1:3, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        PROXY_0=sample(4:6, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        PROXY_2=sample(4:6, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        PROXY_3a=sample(1:4, 5, replace = TRUE))

DATA_2011

  tipo SEXOa PROXY_0 PROXY_2 PROXY_3a
1    A     1       6       6        2
2    B     3       6       4        2
3    C     1       5       4        2
4    D     2       5       4        3
5    E     1       6       5        1
```

Tenemos en este ejemplo cuatro columnas que nos importan, en dos debemos controlar el valor `2` y en las otras el valor a modificar es el `6`. Hay muchas formas para atacar el problema, pero como tenemos la suerte que el valor al que queremos llegar es el 0 en estos casos, podemos hacer un poco de aritmética de matrices para hacerlo bien simple:

```
col_2 <- c("SEXOa", "PROXY_3a")
col_6 <- c("PROXY_0", "PROXY_2")

DATA_2011[, col_2] <- DATA_2011[, col_2] * !DATA_2011[, col_2] == 2
DATA_2011[, col_6] <- DATA_2011[, col_6] * !DATA_2011[, col_6] == 6

DATA_2011

  tipo SEXOa PROXY_0 PROXY_2 PROXY_3a
1    A     1       0       0        0
2    B     3       0       4        0
3    C     1       5       4        0
4    D     0       5       4        3
5    E     1       0       5        1
```

- Por empezar, armamos vectores con los nombres de columna para el valor 2 y el 6
- Luego con `!DATA_2011[, col_2] == 2`, obtenemos una matriz de lógicos, dónde el valor de cada "celda" será Verdadero si es distinto a 2 y Falso si lo es.
- Finalmente con `DATA_2011[, col_2] * !DATA_2011[, col_2]` multiplicamos cada valor original por 0 (si es una celda con un 2) y por 1 si tiene otro valor. Por consiguiente terminamos dejando en 0 solo aquellos datos de interés.
- Tu problema, si esta solución te sirve, se limitaría a definir los nombres de columna para cada tipo de valor a modificar.